# sendKeys cannot type all characters in a string to textarea on Selenium Java

Tags: selenium

In my test case, I use sendKeys to fill a string to a textarea by this commands

```
    WebElement wStmtInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@style='width:100%']"));
    String sString= "SELECT * FROM ABC";
    wStmtInput.clear();
    wStmtInput.sendKeys(sString);
```

It usually send "SELE", "S", "SEL"... some thing like that. I mean It cannot send a full string as I expected.
How I can do now to resolve this issue?

I am testing on the Chrome 58.0.3029.110. My programming language  for selenium test is JAVA.

Comment: does it happens in other browser as well or just chrome? does it happens because string has wildcard character (*), just a wild guess. You can try string without * and see if it's working.

Comment: I didn't check on other browsers! Any way I tried to remove (*) out of my string, unfortunately the issue still occurs!

Comment: add some 5 seconds wait after this  wStmtInput.sendKeys(sString); statement; then it should work fine.

Comment: how about other browsers?

Comment: What is the error returned?  What is the HTML code?  You are likely not getting the web element that you expect to be getting.  You could try substituting "input" for "textarea"

Comment: ah I added Thread.sleep(500) before sendKeys and It looks good until now ! Thank you all very much for your kindly help :))